# phpmyadmin (linux) remove backtick in mysql SQL query window

Tags: mysql, linux, phpmyadmin

I would like to know if there is a away to remove the backtick in the default SQL query window for all queries in phpymyadmin (on Linux)

I'm thinking there might be a phpmyadmin config file responsible for this setting.

For example:
In order to build a query based on the current table *invoices*, I would first click on the SQL tab in phpmyadmin window, and this is what appears:

SELECT * FROM `invoices` WHERE 1

If I then select a table column on the right hand side to add to the query, eg. invoice_number, the query may then read:

SELECT * FROM `invoices` WHERE `invoice_number`

What I want is:
1) for the default SQL (ie when I first press SQL tab) to read:
SELECT * FROM invoices WHERE 1
and
2) as I build the query with selected columns from the right, it would then read:
SELECT * FROM invoices WHERE invoice_number

and so on and so forth.

There surely must be a config setting somewhere in the phpmyadmin environment that I can adjust so that no backtick or quote_backtick ever appears in the SQL I build?

Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: it doesn't seem to be just a config entry: [source](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/blob/master/libraries/sql_query_form.lib.php#L194) (backquote is hardcoded there), but you can easily edit the php file too...

Answer (score 3):

At this point it is easier to modify the **backquote function** in

```
libraries/Util.class.php:881
```

Replace $do_it default value from true to false

public static function backquote($a_name, $do_it = **true**)
to
public static function backquote($a_name, $do_it = **false**)

Comment: Path in phpmyadmin 4.6 on Debian. /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/Util.php

Answer (score 2):

The actual [source code](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/blob/master/libraries/sql_query_form.lib.php#L194) shows that there is no such configuration entry (`backquote` is hardcoded):

A possible solution is to edit these lines in sql_query_form.lib.php:

- [line1](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/blob/master/libraries/sql_query_form.lib.php#L173)

  ```
  $query = PMA_Util::expandUserString(
      $GLOBALS['cfg']['DefaultQueryDatabase'], 'backquote'
  );
  ```

  replace to:

  ```
  $query = PMA_Util::expandUserString(
      $GLOBALS['cfg']['DefaultQueryDatabase']
  );
  ```
- [line2](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/blob/master/libraries/sql_query_form.lib.php#L194)

  ```
  $query = PMA_Util::expandUserString(
      $GLOBALS['cfg']['DefaultQueryTable'], 'backquote'
  );
  ```

  replace to:

  ```
  $query = PMA_Util::expandUserString(
      $GLOBALS['cfg']['DefaultQueryTable']
  );
  ```
- [line3](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/blob/master/libraries/sql_query_form.lib.php#L250)

  ```
  $html .= '<option value="'
      . PMA_Util::backquote(htmlspecialchars($field['Field'])) . '"';
  ```

  replace to:

  ```
  $html .= '<option value="'
      . htmlspecialchars($field['Field']) . '"';
  ```

(It seemed to be working for phpmyadmin 4.0.10.)

Comment: Hi lp_
Thanks for responding so quickly.  I shall give that a look - I have found the file you refer to.

Comment: Worked. An even better solution would strip backticks but conditionally keep them if column name contains space, [reserved words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html#keywords-in-current-series) or non ASCII characters.